# Grouping Json array with Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I have hard time to understand how to group JSON array using Jolt.

I have *input* like this:

```json
{
  "staff": "David",
  "staffId": "D12345",
  "office": "office A",
  "teachClasses":[
    {
      "className": "Intro to Json",
      "classRoom": "room A",
      "day": "Sunday"
    },
    {
      "className": "Intro to Jolt",
      "classRoom": "room C",
      "day": "Saturday"
    },
    {
      "className": "Intro to Json",
      "classRoom": "room B",
      "day": "Friday"
    },
    {
      "className": "Intro to Javascript",
      "classRoom": "room D",
      "day": "Sunday"
    },
    {
      "className": "Intro to Jolt",
      "classRoom": "room E",
      "day": "Wednesday"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to group by "teachClasses.className" into individual objects in an Array.

*Expected output* :

```json
[
  {
    "staff": "David",
    "staffId": "D12345",
    "office": "office A",
    "className": "Intro to Json",
    "teachClasses": [
      {
        "className": "Intro to Json",
        "classRoom": "room A",
        "day": "Sunday"
      },
      {
        "className": "Intro to Json",
        "classRoom": "room B",
        "day": "Friday"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "staff": "David",
    "staffId": "D12345",
    "office": "office A",
    "className": "Intro to Jolt",
    "teachClasses": [
      {
        "className": "Intro to Jolt",
        "classRoom": "room C",
        "day": "Saturday"
      },
      {
        "className": "Intro to Jolt",
        "classRoom": "room E",
        "day": "Wednesday"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "staff": "David",
    "staffId": "D12345",
    "office": "office A",
    "className": "Intro to Javascript",
    "teachClasses": [
      {
        "className": "Intro to Javascript",
        "classRoom": "room D",
        "day": "Sunday"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there way to do this?
Can you show a sample spec and put some explanation?
Also, I am looking for any tutorial to learn the Jolt. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **@(0,className)** as the common value in order to reform objects under common keys, and then trim the key names within the second spec, and pick the leftmost elements by using **cardinality** spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "teachClasses": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,staff)": "@(0,className).staff",
          "@(2,staffId)": "@(0,className).staffId",
          "@(2,office)": "@(0,className).office",
          "@": "@(0,className).&2[]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "staff": "ONE",
        "staffId": "ONE",
        "office": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate!